# Inline edit in table with edit button jquery

Tags: jquery

Following sample code is for making a row editable with edit button.Totally I have 3 buttons,Initially I am hiding the update button.When I click edit button inline edit should be enabled and when I click update inline edit should be disabled.
I wrote the below code and I am unable to find it what I did wrong?

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
        var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
        if ($(this).html() == 'Edit') {
            currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
            $.each(currentTD, function () {
            $(this).prop('contenteditable', true)
            });
        } else {
            $.each(currentTD, function () {
            $(this).prop('contenteditable', false)
            });
        }
        });
```

Complete code: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xcmvzpuk/). 
Main thing is I am using dynamic data so if I click edit only selected row sholuld be able to enable.please Let me know what I did wrong

Comment: what you are trying to achieve by `if ($(this).html() == 'Edit') {`?

Comment: Your else part will never call coz only edit button has class edit.. 
if you specify button `<button class="btn edit update " id="update'+i+'">Update</button>` it will work fine. Your click event will not call on update button so you need to change there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you look at below code. Its just your code only with couple of modifications:

https://jsfiddle.net/xcmvzpuk/5/

```
$('.edit').click(function() {

    var editId = $(this).attr('id'); //here we will get id like edit0 and edit1 and so on
    $("#" + editId).hide();
    var number = editId.replace("edit", ""); //grab the number from id
    $("#update" + number).show();//show the corresponding update button

    var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
    //enable the current row
    $.each(currentTD, function() {
      $(this).prop('contenteditable', true)
    });

  });

  $('.update').click(function() {
    var updateId = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#" + updateId).hide();
    var number = updateId.replace("update", "");
    $("#edit" + number).show();

    var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
    //disable the current row
    $.each(currentTD, function() {
      $(this).prop('contenteditable', false)
    });
  });
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank you so much!

Comment: when we click `edit` button automatically text box with editable should be displayed.instead of hovering over the `td`.Is it possible?I am just asking you.

Comment: right now in your html you just have `<tr>` and `<td>` and on eidt button click you are setting the `contenteditable` property of corresponding `<td>`. So basically there are no text boxes in html. To achieve this; you may need to have textboxes within those `td` and you can manage their visibility just as edit and update button.

Answer (score 0):

Name your `tr` numerically for each row - for example `row1`, `row2`, and add class to potentially editable `td` like `.tdCanEdit` Then make your Edit buttons named accordingly, i.e. `button1`, `button2`.  Then create a function, which takes clicked button - extract it's number. Use this number to get a row id. Find each `.tdCanEdit` classed element in children of your row. Add them your `.contenteditable` class.

Of course, remove all `.contenteditable` classes after finishing.

And avoid `($(this).html() == 'Edit')` check. Use classes instead (add some extra class to buttons).